# Is there anyway to get the average of filesizes? - PHP

Tags: php

I want to get the filesize() of few files and after that I want to display the average of them
And I have a code here that is converting the filesize from bytes to KB, MB and Gb:

```
function formatSizeUnits($bytes)
{
    if ($bytes >= 1073741824)
    {
        $bytes = number_format($bytes / 1073741824, 2) . ' GB';
    }
    elseif ($bytes >= 1048576)
    {
        $bytes = number_format($bytes / 1048576, 2) . ' MB';
    }
    elseif ($bytes >= 1024)
    {
        $bytes = number_format($bytes / 1024, 2) . ' KB';
    }
    elseif ($bytes > 1)
    {
        $bytes = $bytes . ' bytes';
    }
    elseif ($bytes == 1)
    {
        $bytes = $bytes . ' byte';
    }
    else
    {
        $bytes = '0 bytes';
    }

    return $bytes;
}
```

I want to get the average of few files with this.
Is it possible? If it is, please help me.

Comment: Please give some more information.

Comment: @Mahmudhasan For example the average of this files: 1(2985) 2(2124) IS  2554 and the converted file is 25KB

Comment: you want to achieve this 25KB? right?

Comment: @Mahmudhasan I want to get the average of few files dynamically That the average size is converted to KB,Mb and GB

Comment: What files?  Have you tried do using `filesize()`?  Please try and produce some code which can at least list the files you are after.

Comment: @NigelRen Any file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do something like this:

```
$totalSize = 0;
$files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt'];

foreach( $files as $file ) {

    $totalSize += filesize( $file );

}

$averageSize = $totalSize / count( $files );

echo formatSizeUnits( $averageSize );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite ambiguous. According to my understanding, you can add bytes of all your files like:

```
$file_one = filesize('fileone.php');
$file_two = filesize('filetwo.php');
$average = ($file_one + $file_two) /2 ;
```

then run it to the `formatSizeUnits` function. Like:

```
echo formatSizeUnits($average);
```

Hope that's helps you to solve the problem.

Comment: Is there any way to put the file_one and file_two in an array and make it dynamically for for example 3 files and more?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the answer for your question but you could make the function a bit shorter

```
function formatSizeUnits($bytes) {
    if ( $bytes === 1 ) {
        return '1 byte';
    }
    $sizes = ['bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB'];
    $power_10_of_2 = 1024;
    $ind = 0;
    while ( $bytes >= $power_10_of_2 ) {
        $bytes = number_format($bytes / $power_10_of_2, 2, '.', '');
        $ind++;
    }
    return $bytes . ' ' . $sizes[$ind];
}
```